# MVP с фрагментами

Tags: android, mvp

Не могу разобраться как должны общаться между собой активити и фрагменты при MVP.
Например, имеется активити с viewPager, в котором 3 фрагмента, один из которых вызывает другой фрагмент.
1) Как будет выглядеть реализация с MVP? Активити и все фрагменты будут отдельными view, с отдельными презентерами? Или для них будет один презентер?
2) Как должно происходить взаимодействие фрагментов и активити? Как я понимаю активити должна взаимодействовать с фрагментами через презентер?
3) Если фрагмент вызывает другой фрагмент, как должно происходить их взаимодействие?

Comment: Всё сложно как то. Я бы сделал так, если вы хотите отделить бизнес логику отдельно от ui, используйте mvp в fragment, а когда нужно взаимодействовать с activity используйте Callback или передавайте ссылку на activity во fragment

Comment: Фрагмент и так знает о своей активити. Метод `getActivity()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы ответил так:

1. Зависит от того как много кода и функционала. Если допустим на каждом фрагменте 1-2 функции для вызова в-из фрагмента - и в сумме из не превысит 10 - достаточно одного.
2. В самой активити логики быть не должно, она порождает фрагменты, создает или подключается к презентеру и все. любой взаимодействие - через presenter.
3. тут зависит от сложности навигации. Например если это всего 3 фрагмента - эта логика может быть в Presenter. Если больше 5 - лучше выделить отдельный слой Navigotor / Locator.

Хороший пример навигации с MVP c Cicerone https://github.com/terrakok/Cicerone/tree/develop/sample/src/main/java/ru/terrakok/cicerone/sample/mvp

Вот это видео также раскрывает некоторые вопросы структурирования MVP https://events.yandex.ru/lib/talks/5076/